# File corrupt from asynchronous tcp socket

Tags: c#

Created a asynchronous tcp client & server, program works fine when text file transmission but not binary file. No. of byte sent and received are matched but binary file cannot function. pdf with empty content, zip not able to extract etc. Any hints, thanks.

Client

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

// State object for receiving data from remote device.
public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynClient
{
    // The port number for the remote device.
    private const int port = 11000;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.
    private static String response = String.Empty;
    private static String endofFile = "<EOF>";

    private static void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            // The name of the 
            // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("128.127.12.41");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];            
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            //Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
            Send(client, readFile());
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

            // Release the socket.
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    //private static String readFile()
    private static byte[] readFile()
    {
        String filePath = "C:\\way\\interface\\";
        //String fileName = "DC5_2013-04-08_20130828111230.zip";
        String fileName = "DC5_2013-06-01_20130828183818.zip";

        fileName = fileName.Replace("\\", "/");
        while (fileName.IndexOf("/") > -1)
        {
            filePath += fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
            fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
        }

        byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);        
        if (fileNameByte.Length > 850 * 1024)
        {            
            Console.WriteLine("File size is more than 850kb, please try with small file.");            
        }

        byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);        
        byte[] eofByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(endofFile);

        byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length + endofFile.Length];

        fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);        
        fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
        fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
        eofByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length);               

        //return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(clientData);
        return clientData;
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();             
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, byte[] byteData)
    {        
        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        StartClient();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Server

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 860 * 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynServer
{
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static string receivedPath = "C:/way/dw";
    private static String endofFile = "<EOF>";

    public AsynServer()
    {
    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;        

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {            
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));            

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();            
            //Console.WriteLine(content);
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.
                //Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}", content.Length, content);
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket.", content.Length);

                byte[] byteStream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(state.sb.ToString());
                int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteStream, 0);                
                String fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteStream, 4, fileNameLen);                

                writeFile(fileName, fileNameLen, byteStream.Length, byteStream);                


                // Echo the data back to the client.
                //Send(handler, content);
                Send(handler, "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeFile(String fileName, int fileNameLen, int receiveByte, byte[] receiveBuffer)
    {        
        BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + "/" + fileName, FileMode.Append));                
        bWrite.Write(receiveBuffer, 4 + fileNameLen, receiveByte - 4 - fileNameLen - endofFile.Length);
        bWrite.Close();
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }


    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        StartListening();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem is in your receive code on the server. You're converting binary data to a string with this:

```
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
```

ASCII is a 7-bit encoding. Any character that is not in the range 0 to 127 will be converted to "?". So approximately half of your binary data is getting converted to question marks.

Another problem you'd have here is if the string `"<EOF>"` occurs somewhere in a text file (or a binary file). If that happened, your receiver would quit before the entire file were read.

You should change your protocol so that rather than sending an `"<EOF>"` string, you put the total length of what you're sending in the first 4 bytes of the data that you send. Your receive code reads the first 4 bytes and knows how many total bytes it's supposed to receive.

Treat *everything* as binary when you receive it. When you pull the file name out, you convert *just those bytes* to a string. But all of the file data must be treated as binary. Just write it directly to the output file. Or you can buffer it in memory if you need to.

I wouldn't recommend using `Encoding.ASCII` even for the file name. It's possible to have non-ASCII characters in Windows file names. I would recommend using `Encoding.UTF8`, which will encode ASCII characters in a single byte, but also allows for the full Unicode character set.